# can I compare only the values of a dictionary and a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries one that is key with multiple values {'1': ['A','b',...]'2':['c','D',...]}
and another that is nested {'1': [{'a': '0.166000'},{'b': '0.166000'},{'c': '0.254968'},...

I want to compare the values of the first dictionary A,b,c,D with the values from the nested dictionary a,b,c and basically if they match move it to a separate file.
for example I would have in a text file
1    b     0.166000
2    c     0.254968

Comment: Find code that makes the necessary change to a single key-value pair, then see the techniques from the linked duplicate to apply it to the entire dictionary. There is not anything simpler than that.